# Prompt User for image URL in python

Tags: python-2.7, input, python-requests

I have the following code:

```
import requests
from StringIO import StringIO

responseL = requests.get(url)
imL = Image.open(StringIO(responseL.content))

responseR = requests.get(url)
imR = Image.open(StringIO(responseR.content))
```

I am trying to find a way to instead prompt the user for a URL for their image so that they can input a url from an image from for example photobucket or imgur. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: tried `url = raw_input("Enter url")` ?

Comment: Thank you, I could not for the life of me finding that in a search.